# Quick Union Functional Style

Tags: algorithm, scala, functional-programming, sbt

I am trying to mix study with pleasure by implementing the exercises from Sedgewick and Wayne's "Algorithm's 4th Edition" in scala (and, to the best of my know-how, in a functional style).

At the exercises 1.5.7 I blocked and hope that someone could help me out. So the task is to write the QuickUnion implementation. You may find [Java implementation here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/QuickUnionUF.java.html).

I've written my scala version and it seems to make sense, but the console output is outright discouraging. I am creating an array of 625 initial components but ... the number of components at the end is .. below zero

Without further ado this is my implementation:

```
package ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_5_7.quickUnionUF

import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class QuickUnionUF(size: Int) extends AbstractUF(size) {

  override val array = (0 to size).toArray

  override def find(p: Int): Int = {
    validate(p)
    Stream.iterate(p)(p => array(p)).dropWhile { _ != array(p) }.head
  }

  override def connected(p: Int, q: Int): Boolean = find(p) == find(q)

  override def union(p: Int, q: Int) = {
    /*
     * need to declare Futures outisde
     * for-comprehension loop to run in parallel
     */
    val fRootP = Future { find(p) }
    val fRootQ = Future { find(q) }

    for {
      rootP <- fRootP
      rootQ <- fRootQ
      if (rootP != rootQ)
    } {
      array(rootP) = rootQ
      count -= 1
    }
  }

}
```

The parent [abstract class](https://github.com/vasigorc/Algorithms/blob/master/Chapter%201%20Fundamentals/algorithms1_5_7/src/main/scala/ca/vgorcinschi/algorithms1_5_7/quickUnionUF/AbstractUF.scala) and the [underlying trait](https://github.com/vasigorc/Algorithms/blob/master/Chapter%201%20Fundamentals/algorithms1_5_7/src/main/scala/ca/vgorcinschi/algorithms1_5_7/quickUnionUF/UF.scala) are both in my github repository. For ease of reading I am copying below the Main class:

```
import scala.io.Source
import ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_5_7.quickUnionUF.QuickUnionUF
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Main extends App {
  val allLines = Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/mediumUF.txt").getLines().toList
  //get & print the initial number of components
  val size = allLines.head.trim.toInt
  println(s"Le nombre initial de composants est $size")

  val uf = new QuickUnionUF(size)

  val Integer = new Regex("(-)?(\\d+)")

  for (line <- allLines.tail) {
    val p = Integer findFirstIn line

    assert(p.isDefined)

    val intP = p.get toInt
    val q = Integer findFirstIn line.substring(p.get.length).replace("\\s+", "")

    assert(q.isDefined)

    val intQ = q.get.toInt
    if (!uf.connected(intP, intQ)) {
      uf.union(intP, intQ)
      println(s"L`union fait sur $intP et $intQ")
      println(s"Le nombre des composants est maintenant - ${uf.counter()}")
    }
  }
}
```

In addition these are the first and the last lines of the run output:

```
> runMain Main
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/vgorcinschi/workspace-scala/Algorithms/Chapter 1 Fundamentals/algorithms1_5_7/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[info] Running Main 
Le nombre initial de composants est 625
L`union fait sur 528 et 503
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 624
L`union fait sur 548 et 523
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 623
L`union fait sur 389 et 414
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 622
L`union fait sur 446 et 421
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 621
L`union fait sur 552 et 553
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 620
L`union fait sur 154 et 155
...
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - -67
L`union fait sur 463 et 464
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - -67
L`union fait sur 10 et 35
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - -67
L`union fait sur 619 et 594
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - -67
L`union fait sur 403 et 402
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - -67
```

I do fear that the shoe pinches somewhere around my futures or the stream based find, but I can't seem to figure it out...

Comment: Doesn't work very well with Scala SDK plugin in Eclipse. But thank you for the "valuable" comment. Great expertise :-)

Comment: Scala support in eclipse sucks. Get intellij. For the future, sarcasm isn't the best way to get help around here (or anywhere else for that matter).

Comment: I strongly recommend that you re-read your initial comment before accusing others of sarcasm. As the call, so the echo.

Comment: @Dima "But I can afford..." - arrogance and narcissism. That reminds me of Orwell's "..all animals are equal, but some animals are more equal than the others.." :-) I doubt you even read the question let alone made an intellectual effort of thinking what went wrong. "try to debug" is a lofty reply that can be used for 99% of all Stack Overflow questions - including yours. It is reluctance to help and not a real answer.

Comment: Nope, neither. Just and observation, that you can catch more flies with honey than manure.

Comment: Orwell was talking about politics,  this is common courtesy. You made me waste five minutes of my life trying to parse your wall of code because you don't know how to use debuggers. So, I responded with a sarcastic comment (that can still be useful to you if your were willing to learn rather than just persist in your rightfulness). And no, it is not used in 99% of questions, only in those, that like yours are clearly an attempt by the author to get someone else debug the problem for them.These questions are out-or-topic on SSO. This is not "debug my code for me" site, rather "help me learn".

Comment: no, buddy. I did use debug and by the way told you that there are issues with using it in Eclipse (expressions view in particular). You think that your rank that you inflated inclusively by googling out the questions and trying to be the first on the spot permits you to look at and treat others with loftiness. I found the solution myself thanks to code analysis and not your help. Continue to inflate your fake ranking.

Comment: Yes. I said  that there are "issues" with eclipse, and recommended a tool that you should be using instead. This is the best advice you can get for a problem like this around here. I don't care about my rank, and you know nothing about how I got it. If you think googling is a good resource for answering questions on SO, you might want to consider using it yourself next time, before posting your code online and asking people to debug it for you, because you are using a wrong tool, and "have issues".
You found the solution yourself - good for you. This question should have never been posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. The solution was odd because it makes me wonder how does the original solution even worked. Basically I just rewrote the counter() in the parent class to return a `array.distinct.length` , i.e. the distinct integers or the roots:

```
/*
 * takes the initial number of components
 * as its argument
 */
abstract class AbstractUF(var count: Int) extends UF{

  override def counter() = array.distinct.length

  val array: Array[Int]

...
}
```

Output:

```
Le nombre initial de composants est 625
L`union fait sur 528 et 503
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 625
L`union fait sur 548 et 523
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 624
L`union fait sur 389 et 414
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 623
L`union fait sur 446 et 421
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 622
L`union fait sur 552 et 553
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 621
L`union fait sur 154 et 155
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 620
...
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 266
L`union fait sur 295 et 320
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 266
L`union fait sur 160 et 159
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 266
L`union fait sur 463 et 464
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 266
L`union fait sur 10 et 35
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 266
L`union fait sur 619 et 594
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 265
L`union fait sur 403 et 402
Le nombre des composants est maintenant - 265
```